# android - okhttp - how to trust expired SSL certificates

Tags: android, certificate, okhttp

In some android  devices,  the  system  time  is  1970 . So  I  just  want to  trust expired SSL certificates . But I  don't want  to  trust  all certificates .

Comment: You can always implement your own `X509TrustManager`. But to me it seems like you're trying to fix something in your app which really is a user error. Either they've changed a setting that they're not supposed to change, or their device is broken and they should have it fixed / get a new device.

Comment: @Michael   Yes, you are right, . But  most  of  user  are  stupid .  They  don't know how  to change  time  sometions.  I don't know   how  to  implement  X509TrustManager  to    trust  expired SSL certificates